# QML Column does not work well with Repeater

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Dialog component that supposedly be a table. When the use calling its function `openDialog(inputCellContent)` and pass in a 2D Javascript array, it would display the content like an excel table.

The data passed in is expected to have 5 columns. Here's my attempt to do that in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1

import "../widgets"

Dialog {
    width: Math.min(1024, parent.width - 20)
    height: Math.min(768, parent.height - 20)
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    modal: true
    focus: true
    title: "GCP Output accuracy"

    property var cellWidth: 125;
    property var buttonWidth: 100;
    property var cellContent: [];

    function openDialog(inputCellContent) {
        cellContent = inputCellContent;
        open();
    }

    Pane {
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent

            Text {
                visible: cellContent.length == 0

                text: "No accuracy analysis found. Please rerun the dataset."
                font.bold: true
                color: "red"
            }

            Row {
                id: headerRow
                visible: cellContent.length > 0

                width: parent.width
                Repeater {
                    model: ["id", "x", "y", "z", "error_distance"]

                    TextField {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        wrapMode: TextField.Wrap
                        width: cellWidth
                        text: modelData
                        readOnly: true
                    }
                }
            }

            ScrollView {
                visible: cellContent.length > 0

                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height - headerRow.height
                Layout.fillWidth: true  
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: true

                ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

                Column {
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    Repeater {
                        id: rowRepeater
                        anchors.fill: parent

                        width: parent.width

                        model: cellContent
                        Row {
                            width: parent.width

                            Repeater {
                                id: columnRepeater
                            
                                model: cellContent[index]
                                TextField {
                                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                    wrapMode: TextField.Wrap
                                    width: cellWidth
                                    text: modelData
                                    readOnly: true
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

However, upon trying this I got weird result if I try calling `openDialog(inputCellContent)` in the following order:

1. Pass in a valid 2D array and close the dialog.
2. Pass in an empty array and close the dialog.
3. Pass in a valid 2D array again and see that all cells are squished into one row (see images).

First step result:
[image: First step result]

Third step result:
[image: Third step result]

This is obviously not what I have anticipated at all. Any insights into why is it happening? Thanks!

Comment: Quick side question - wouldn't a TableView be an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Regardless, you are mixing up a number of techniques here. First, children of layouts should be sized using Layout.* properties only. Setting their width and height directly will confuse things. Second, ScrollView needs its contentHeight and contentWidth set or else it will rely on the intrinsic height and width of its child. I think you'll need to make this a runnable example project we can download and run locally if you want a full diagnosis and fixes.